# How to rotate ylab in basic plot R

Tags: r

I've created three plots, I want to set the ylab text on the top and rotate text in `ylab = "text"`, but I can't do it using text, or `par("usr")` and draw a new axis. How to do it?

```
steps1 <- c(77:82)
steps2 <- c(72:82)
steps3 <- c(62:82)
opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(las = 1)
plot(steps1, dfL1_F[77:82],
type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = 'Max F, A.U.')
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
plot(steps2, dfL1_F[72:82],
type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = 'Max F, A.U.')
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red") 
plot(steps3, dfL1_F[62:82],
type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = 'Max F, A.U.')
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red")   
par(opar)
```

Sorry, for trouble, this is input data:

```
c(0.090803, 0.053571, 0.059279, 0.081256, 0.898884, 0.046667, 0.036066, 
0.024925, 0.109469, 0.030897, 0.052733, 0.013766, 0.012801, 
0.012609, 0.009315, 0.015449, 0.031633, 0.009842, 0.014112, 0.016614, 
0.006702, 0.006865, 0.007912, 0.023806, 0.023373, 0.009024, 0.008952, 
0.042152, 0.010782, 0.006892, 0.006798, 0.006797, 0.006586, 0.020231, 
0.040914, 0.007164, 0.008807, 0.004308, 0.009495, 0.008776, 0.006001, 
0.004247, 0.052963, 0.006756, 0.02555, 0.002508, 0.003779, 0.00453, 
0.003253, 0.006861, 0.009106, 0.001776, 0.004892, 0.005216, 0.010059, 
0.0045, 0.003041, 0.005896, 0.00287, 0.003333, 0.008464, 0.003295, 
0.002963, 0.001889, 0.0021, 0.001508, 0.002127, 0.001287, 0.001515, 
0.001391, 0.002729, 0.002551, 0.001971, 0.001635, 0.000612, 0.00097, 
0.000504, 3e-04, 0.000385, 0.000322, 0.000111, 0.000111)
```

Comment: Could you share your data so we can help? You can do this by copying and pasting the output of `dput(dfL1_F)` into your question.

Comment: Usually use `axis()` to draw an axis, and `mtext()` (margin text) for a custom axis label. If you need more help, please share enough data for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @neuron 
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UxjiZZeUfR1LI3GxqwRimmKce6dAVbfE/view?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: @Alex copy and paste the output from `dput()` directly into your question. The above comment is not the format `dput()` outputs data

Comment: @Alex so are you just trying to put the y-axis on the top of the graph? I am not sure what you mean when you say "ylab text on the top"? Do you not want a y label?

Comment: I meant how can I put the ylabel up in the corner, and rotate the text 90 degrees. Y-axis have a label  "MAX F" (ylab)

Comment: @Alex and what did you mean by "draw a new axis"?

Comment: @neuron I try to edit y label using  this manual:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459314/r-how-to-rotate-label-of-secondary-y-axis-base

Comment: @Alex So you just want to move the y label and that's it?

Comment: @neuron
yes, move ylab to top and rotate text ylab (MAX F) at 90 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `ylab` and create an adjustable `ylab` using `mtext` Using `mtext` you can move the title left and right using `adj`, move the title up and down using `padj`, and change the size of the font using `cex`. You may have to play with `padj` and `adj` a bit to get the label in the right position for your needs

```
steps1 <- c(77:82)
steps2 <- c(72:82)
steps3 <- c(62:82)
opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(las = 1)
plot(steps1, dfL1_F[77:82],
     type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = '')
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red")
#adj will move the title left and right and padj moves the title up and down
mtext("MAX F", col = "black", adj=-0.4, padj=-1, cex=0.6)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
plot(steps2, dfL1_F[72:82],
     type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = '')
#adj will move the title left and right and padj moves the title up and down
mtext("MAX F.", col = "black", adj=-0.4, padj=-1, cex=0.6)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red") 
plot(steps3, dfL1_F[62:82],
     type= "o",pch=16, lty=1, col="black", xlab = 'Step finals', ylab = '')
#adj will move the title left and right and padj moves the title up and down
mtext("MAX F", col = "black", adj=-0.4, padj=-1, cex=0.6)
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
abline(h=c(0.000450), lwd=1.5, lty=2, col="red")   
par(opar)
```

[image: example1]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @neuron